# Find max value of list items in automation anywhere360

Tags: list, automation, max, automationanywhere

I look for something like the Python max()-Function in Automation Anywhere.
I looped through a parent folder which has 5 subfolders and received the last modified dates of these subfolders with the files and folder: folder attribute action. I know want to access the last modified folder.

Easy to solve with Python but I cannot find a solution within AA 360.

Does someone has a solution to the issue?